# How do I keep 'indent' from moving curly braces to the next line?

Tags: indentation

I have several empty inline function definitions in C++ like so:

```
class C
{
    void foo(){}
    void bar(){}
};
```

now if I run `indent -st -i4 -nut test.cc` in order to just fix the indentation I get

```
class C
{
    void foo ()
    {
    }
    void bar ()
    {
    }
};
```

But I just want to fix the indentation without moving curly braces around!

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `indent` is designed for C and is known to not work well with C++.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: it's not just that, there doesn't seem to be an option for specific formatting of empty blocks.